# Gulp with TypeDoc error

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typedoc

I m trying to run the gulp task for TypeDoc but i m getting this errors for every ts file i have

```
 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning
```

my gulp file :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var typedoc = require("gulp-typedoc");
gulp.task("typedoc", function() {
    return gulp
        .src(["src/**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(typedoc({
            module: "commonjs",
            target: "es5",
            out: "docs/",
            name: "My project title"
        }))
        ;
});
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `experimentalDecorators` option to your gulpfile, as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');    

var typedoc = require("gulp-typedoc");
gulp.task("typedoc", function() {
    return gulp
        .src(["src/**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(typedoc({
            module: "commonjs",
            target: "es5",
            out: "docs/",
            name: "My project title",
            "experimentalDecorators": "true",
        }))
        ;
});
```